# R: floating point errors in simple math operations

Tags: r, floating-point, floating-accuracy

So of course:

```
1023.1 - 0.1 < 1023
[1] FALSE
```

but...

```
1024.1 - 0.1 < 1024
[1] TRUE
```

Is this a bug? Is it expected behaviour?
Is there some way I can avoid this, such as rounding all my numbers to like 10 significant digits (but this sounds terrible). I know about functions such as all.equal() but I am not attempting comparisons, I got here because this leads to unpredicted failures in other functions such as:

```
start = 1024
end = 1024 - 0.1
seq(start, end, by=0.1)
```

given that the numbers are variable and out of my control what is the best practice to clean/proof my variables to avoid these type of issues?

This is on windows 10 if it makes any difference. R version 4.2.2

Comment: An R specific discussion can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: For the special case of `seq(…, by =)`, the answer is to only use integer arguments for `by`, and then dividing the result; e.g. in your case `seq(10240, 10239, by = 1) / 10`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: For further reading on this issue, and some of R's other foibles, check out [The R Inferno](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwixy7GxgrSDAxUAsVYBHUA2APoQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.burns-stat.com%2Fpages%2FTutor%2FR_inferno.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ccYVJrqViLKxffdLT6tdj&opi=89978449) by Patrick Burns.